# PHP MYSQL unserialize() issues

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I have a "recruiter" table in my database which has different attributes and one of them is "Professions". `"Professions"` is a serialized array which I get from a multiple select form. And this works fine.

When I unserialize this attribute nothing is printed - no error, no text.

This is a code I was testing serialization with:

```
$sql = 'SELECT Company_name, Status, Size, Professions, Seniority_levels, Sector, Website, Location FROM Recruiter';
$query = mysql_query($sql, $con);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_BOTH)){
    $recruiters[] = array($result[0], $result[1], $result[2], $result[3], $result[4], $result[5], $result[6], $result[7]);
}

foreach($recruiters AS $recruiter){
    $test = unserialize($recruiter[3]);
    echo $test[0].'<br>';
}
```

So basically $test[0] prints nothing although the new lines are printed. Please help!

Comment: That's kind of trouble one gets when storing serialized data in the database. Try to change the table's structure.

Comment: Sorry i ment Professions not Sectors. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test = unserialize($recruiter[3]);` should become `test = unserialize($recruiter[5]);` since the sector field is the sixth column .

However what if somewhere in the future you might need to select rows where sectors equal smth ? serialize whont help you then so i suggest you have a look at a different implementation for the sector filed witch is called bitwize http://www.litfuel.net/tutorials/bitwise.htm

---

Edit

Asuming you hit the right column and the column contains `a:1:{i:0;s:27: a:1:{i:0;s:27: a:38:{i:0;s:27: a:9:{i:0;s:39:`, it looks like the serialized array is not fully saved in you're db, it's only part of it . So the unserialize function whont return you an array . Have a look at the length of the mysql field i assume you've set it smaller than you need so you're data is trimmed on insert/update .

---

Edit

`a:1:{i:0;s:27:` you're still missing the rest of the serialized array . `s:27:` means a string is following containint 27 characters, and you're serialized array stops there when it should look like 
`a:1:{i:0;s:27:"123456789012345678901234567";}`

( `a:1` stands for an array containing 1 value with it's content between `{}`, `i:0;` is the array key 0, `s:27:"";` stands for a string containing 27 characters as the value for the `i:0` key ) .

Comment: Sorry i ment Professions, not Sectors. Also printing test without unserialization give me a:1:{i:0;s:27:
a:1:{i:0;s:27:
a:38:{i:0;s:27:
a:9:{i:0;s:39:

Comment: No you got it wrong. It prints 4 times the result, so one column contains a:1:{i:0;s:27:, another contains a:1:{i:0;s:27: etc.

Comment: nope, i didn't got it wrong see the last edit . and please check you're length of the Professions mysql field .

Comment: Ok so maybe something is wrong in my database? The Professions attribute was set to be "text" with no "maximum length" set.

Comment: When I add data through the form when there is a "varchar(50)" set, the data stored looks the same. a:1:{i:0;s:24:

Comment: run this query and edit you're question with it's output : `SHOW CREATE TABLE Recruiter;` , maybe you have a problem when you insert/update the table .

Comment: I think this is not a big problem just everything needs to be veryfied. Can we talk on some messenger?

Comment: i whont be able to help you out if i don't see the result from the query, nor here nor on messenger ( my ym id is poelinca, but i whont be available for long ).

Comment: CREATE TABLE `Recruiter` (
 `Recruiter_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Company_name` text COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
 `Status` text COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
 `Size` text COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
 `Professions` varchar(50) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
 `Seniority_levels` varchar(50) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
 `Sector` varchar(50) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
 `Website` text COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
 `Location` text COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Recruiter_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii COLLATE=ascii_bin

Comment: oki so set you're Professions field back to text with no maximum length, delete everithing in the table and start to test you're form on insrert . insert a field then check the values with phpmyadmin, if you don't have the full serialized array then check the code that does the insert .

Comment: Ok i changed the fields back to text, deleted all data from the table and inserted 3 new records by the form. The data inside professions is again a:1:{i:0;s:24:

Comment: $sql = 'INSERT INTO `Recruiter` (`Recruiter_ID`, `Company_name`, `Status`, `Size`, `Professions`, `Seniority_levels`, `Sector`, `Website`, `Location`) 
VALUES (\'\', \''.$_POST['name'].'\',
\''.$_POST['status'].'\',
\''.$_POST['size'].'\',
                                 \''.$_POST['professions'].'\', 
                                 \''.$_POST['levels'].'\', 
\''.$_POST['sectors'].'\',
\''.$_POST['url'].'\',
\''.$_POST['continent'].'\')';
mysql_query($sql, $con);

Comment: `$_POST['professions']` is a serialized array allready ? from where do you send that serialized array ?

Comment: Ok I have found where is the problem. I first select data, then go to the confirmation page to show what is selected. I there serialize it and send and when a button is pressed serialized data is sent again by post. And here is the problem, when I send serialized data by post I recieve wrong data!

EDIT

The serialized data send by POST ends in the place where " should appear.

Comment: Ok thanks to you I know where is the problem and I know now how should I deal with it. Thanks for help and you answer will be approved :)

Answer (score 1):

try printing the $test array and the $recruiters and the $recruiter arrays. See if the result is fine before the unserialisation of the data. If the query returns any data. Also try the while loop with mysql_fetch_assoc. Let me know of the results and if this solves the problem

Comment: printing $test = $recruiter[3], so as array gives me: a:1:{i:0;s:27:
a:1:{i:0;s:27:
a:38:{i:0;s:27:
a:9:{i:0;s:39:

Comment: hmmmm... thats strange...could you please try printing unserialize($recruiter[3]); I think the problem might be that the array you have created might not have $test[0] instead have something like $test[1]; so print the unserialized results for $test and see what comes up and tell me.

Comment: Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysql_fetch_assoc() in /srv/disk7/783806/www/piotrchabros.pl/results.php on line 70

Comment: try printing the unserialized $test instead of $test[0];

Comment: Printing unserialize($recruiter[3]) prints nothing.

Comment: also change it back to mysql_fetch_array($querry, MYSQL_BOTH)){

Comment: I changed it to mysql_fetch_array and printed test = unserialize($recruiter[3]) and nothing was printed

Comment: You can see it by yourself by going to the site im testing it, the changes are in real time - www.piotrchabros.pl/results.php

Comment: did you try print_r($recruiter[3]);

Comment: print_r{$recruiter[3]) give me N;N;N;N;

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the data. I think the serialized data might be corrupt but thats not quite possible. I think that your database did not save the complete serialized data when you created the record in the first place. Go check the table and make sure it is varchar and of suitable lenght. If the lenght was too short then this might have happened and you may need to reinsert the data. Otherwise your code seems fine..

Comment: It was set to text - not varchar. I have changed it to varchar with length of 50. But still nothing is printed.